# Background Image not loading in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Following is my fiddle and the only issue I am facing is that my background image is not displaying only in internet explorer. Kindly let me know how to fix this issue. I tried alot but failed

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/R6K5S/7/)

**CODE**

```
.header2 {
    background: #6cab26;
    background-image: url(http://freepsdgraphics.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/free-web-header-download-550x172.jpg), #5D5846;
    background-image: url(http://freepsdgraphics.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/free-web-header-download-550x172.jpg), -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #FFFFFF 0%, rgba(93,88,70,1) 100%);
    background-image: url(http://freepsdgraphics.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/free-web-header-download-550x172.jpg), -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 460, color-stop(0%, #FFFFFF), color-stop(100%, rgba(93,88,70,1)));
    background-image: url(http://freepsdgraphics.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/free-web-header-download-550x172.jpg), -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #FFFFFF 0%, rgba(93,88,70,1) 100%);
    background-image: url(http://freepsdgraphics.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/free-web-header-download-550x172.jpg), -o-radial-gradient(circle, #FFFFFF 0%, rgba(93,88,70,1) 100%);
    background-image: url(http://freepsdgraphics.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/free-web-header-download-550x172.jpg), -ms-radial-gradient(circle, #FFFFFF 0%, rgba(93,88,70,1) 100%);
    background-image: url(http://freepsdgraphics.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/free-web-header-download-550x172.jpg), radial-gradient(circle, #FFFFFF 0%, rgba(93,88,70,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b9b8b1', endColorstr='#5d5846', GradientType=1 ), progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="http://freepsdgraphics.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/free-web-header-download-550x172.jpg" , sizingMethod='scale'); 
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:210px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle !important;
    color: red;

}
```

Comment: which IE you are using ?

Comment: You can use `background` instead of `background-image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your

```
background-image: url(http://freepsdgraphics.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/free-web-header-download-550x172.jpg) #5D5846;
```

and add

```
background-image: url(http://freepsdgraphics.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/free-web-header-download-550x172.jpg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Ultimate CSS Gradient generator tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) which also supports IE9.

just copy the relevant css (the one that contain gradient code) to the tool and check the ie9 support checkbox.

Also note that it states that in order for IE9 to support it, you need to remove the filter:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .header2 {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I just check it issue was happening because of this line `background-image: url(http://freepsdgraphics.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/free-web-header-download-550x172.jpg), #5D5846;`